# Can I be given a second chance regarding a stupid action of mine?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging

Since the only 2 people who can still see my answer are @goldPseudo and @Medi1Saif I'll point this question towards them.
On this [page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49181/how-to-interpret-the-ahadith-about-joining-two-prayers-due-to-rain) my answer got 2 downvotes which soon afterwards got deleted for abusive and copy-paste entirely chunks of text from other islam related sites. I'm sorry for that, I won't do that again. Can I please get my 100 points back by letting me delete the question? I won't do it again.

P.S.:

Is 100 points as punishment not too much? That's like 3-4 months of my progress on this forum. 
Note that I don't share the same view as the information provided in the answer. My apologies.

Comment: Well I could undelete it, but I have a strong doubt that most of it is taken from the fatwa on islamqa which would mean it falls under plagiarism. I know this fatwa as I post questions there and check many answers there each day to filter what one could use or not. I've found 2-3 (different) answers for the same question in there. Note anybody who has >4K rep could read your answer (See [privileges](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)), unless he uses the mobile app as in my case.

Comment: I provided the sources too. Is it still plagiarism if I referred the sources?

Comment: If you don't mark it as a quote yes! And if it is the major part of the answer say 90% or more.

Comment: Oh, ok. Can I please get my 100 points back? Because I need to go the library.

Comment: I have no idea about how and where you lost your rep.

Comment: Well if your answer gets registered as spam doesn't make you lose 100 points, then I don't know either. But I'm certain that I had 255 points as shown on the graph on my profile.

Comment: And it seems 4 other users need to vote for undeletion. I'd appreciate other users if you'd help me out.

Comment: I might undelete and edit it. But I don't think that would change your rep

Comment: You are right. So 100 points are gone, now I have to wait 3-4 months to earn it back. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will quote here the contentious paragraph:

> As for the School of Hanafis [jurisprudence], they have prohibited the combination [of prayers] absolutely, with exception being at `Arafa and al-Muzdalifa. [This is] despite the presence of numerous clear sahih (authentic traditions) which allow the combination, especially when traveling. However, despite the clear [traditions], they (the School of Hanafis) interpreted them to refer to an unintentional combination (al-jam' al-suri). The invalidity of this [view] will become clear to you soon, God willing.

This is condescending. There is no other way to describe it. Do you honestly think that any Hanafi who reads this is going to think "Man, I sure feel like my beliefs are being respected here"?

The entire point of that paragraph is to prove that the Hanafi beliefs are wrong and that Hanafis should feel bad until they agree with whoever wrote the article. This is pretty much the textbook definition of what [Be nice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) is intended to prevent: "**Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on…religion…will not be tolerated. At all.**"

The fact that you're hiding behind the fact that you were only quoting someone else instead of espousing the opinions yourself doesn't change the fact that **you, personally, are the one who posted it**. If you can't even understand *what* you're posting — not even to the point of being able to write it in your own words — and especially if your unwilling to stand behind it *after* you've posted it, **you probably shouldn't be posting it in the first place**.

tl;dr: You posted offensive content, and it was flagged it for being offensive. Simple as that.

Comment: Well, I've noticed that and I apologised for it. That's why I want to delete it myself so that I can get my points back. First and last time.

Comment: @AnonymousI I am in no way inclined to reverse the flag, but I have asked another mod to review the decision. We'll see what he says.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration.

Comment: As a way to show the sincerity of my apologies, see [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49198/what-are-the-limits-of-verbally-forbidding-evil-according-to-the-sunnah-quran).